# List version of SphericalPlot3D

Tags: plotting

could you give me some input on how to create a list version of

```
SphericalPlot3D[r[theta,phi],{theta,min,max},{phi,min,max}]
```

When r[] is an explicit analytical function it's not an issue, but what if one numerically generates a list {{r1,theta1,phi1},...,{rn,thetan,phin}} and wants to visualize it in a similar manner? Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 8):

A quick way of doing this would be to take the data and apply an [`Interpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Interpolation.html) to create a function that can be plotted with `SphericalPlot3D`. Here is an example:

```
data = Flatten[
   Table[{{theta, phi}, 
     N@Re@SphericalHarmonicY[2, 1, theta, phi]}, {theta, Pi/10, Pi, 
     Pi/10}, {phi, Pi/10, 2 Pi, Pi/10}], 1];

f = Interpolation[data];

SphericalPlot3D[f[theta, phi], {theta, 0, Pi}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image: 3D]

Here you get a warning because extrapolation was used since the data range is smaller than the angle range I'm plotting. But that's normal.

Note that the data has to be arranged differently from the structure you gave in the question: It's of the form `{{{theta1, phi1}, f1}, {{{theta2, phi2}, f2}, ...}`

Answer (score 2):

I was considering to advise the use of `ListSurfacePlot3D` to do this, but after tinkering with it for some while, I found it is awful for reconstruction of spherical plots.

Let's take an example from the documentation:

```
SphericalPlot3D[1 + 2 Cos[2 θ], {θ , 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The surface could be sampled like this:

```
data = Flatten[Table[{1 + 2 Cos[2 θ], θ, ϕ}, {θ, 0, Pi, Pi/30}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/30}], 1];
```

In v9 we have got an easy way to transform coordinates form spherical to Cartesian:

```
mapping =  CoordinateTransformData["Spherical" -> "Cartesian", "Mapping"]
```

> {Cos[#1[[3]]] Sin[#1[[2]]] #1[[1]], Sin[#1[[2]]] Sin[#1[[3]]] #1[[1]], Cos[#1[[2]]] #1[[1]]} &

Those without v9 can use the pure function in the output above.

This works fine with`ListPointPlot3D`:

```
ListPointPlot3D[mapping /@ data, BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However, it gets absolutely horrible results with `ListSurfacePlot3D`

```
ListSurfacePlot3D[mapping /@ data, BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Increasing sampling density doesn't help at all. Neither does the application of the `MaxPlotPoints->Infinity` option. So, it looks like that Jens' answer is the best solution in this case.

Comment: This is quite odd.  With `/90` in both Table iterators and `MaxPlotPoints -> 125` I get this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/s1G7n.png  Fairly different, wouldn't you say? :^)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Are you sure you havent used ListPlot3D instead of ListSurfacePlot3D?

Comment: @mr.wizard Back at the keyboard and can confirm what you got there. I tried increasing MaxPlotPoints to 500, but it brings my PC to its knees.

Comment: I think this is worthy of its own question.  I'd like to know why that happens and if there are Method options etc., that better handle this case.  Will you ask?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It doesn't look answerable to me. Perhaps more an issue for WRI support.