# SphericalPlot3D for a list

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

This question was asked before ([here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22444/list-version-of-sphericalplot3d)), but I couldn't get the answers to work.
I have a list of values

```
List1=Table[{theta,phi,f1[theta,phi]},{theta,0,Pi,Pi/10},{phi,0,2Pi,2Pi/10}]
List2=Table[{theta,phi,f2[theta,phi]},{theta,0,Pi,Pi/10},{phi,0,2Pi,2Pi/10}]
f=Table[{List1[[i,j,1]],List1[[i,j,2]],List1[[i,j,3]]^2+List2[[i,j,3]]^2},{i,1,Length[List1]},{j,1,Length[List1[[1]]]}]
```

Sample functions for f1 and f2:

```
f1[theta,phi]=Sin[3 theta]Cos[phi];
f2[theta,phi]=Cos[theta] Sin[phi];
```

How do I get SphericalPlot3D of f from this list? Any help would be appreciated. TIA!

Comment: What are the definitions of `f1` and `f2`?

Comment: @BobHanlon They're complicated functions of theta and phi, which is why I didn't want to write them down. I just wanted a general way of getting to the SphericalPlot.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to post your actual functions; however, you should include some simple examples. Either one person (you) goes through the effort of making up some functions or everyone who is willing to help you has to do it.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I'll edit it to include functions. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f1[theta_, phi_] = Sin[3 theta] Cos[phi];
f2[theta_, phi_] = Cos[theta] Sin[phi];

List1 = Flatten[
   Table[{{theta, phi}, f1[theta, phi]}, {theta, 0, Pi, Pi/10}, {phi, 
     0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/10}], 1];

List2 = Flatten[
   Table[{{theta, phi}, f2[theta, phi]}, {theta, 0, Pi, Pi/10}, {phi, 
     0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/10}], 1];

funcs = Interpolation /@ {List1, List2}
```

[image]

```
SphericalPlot3D[Evaluate@Through[funcs[theta, phi]],
 {theta, 0, Pi}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi},
 PlotPoints -> 50,
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]